# How do I move the gesture button in Dolphin HD?

Tags: dolphin-browser

Before the Sonar changes, I could move the gesture button by long-pressing it and dragging it to a different corner. Now long pressing brings up a menu to use a gesture or use Sonar.

How can I move the gesture button to a different corner?

Comment: I had looked around the settings menus for what felt like _hours_ before I found those button's settings (see Sachin Shekhar's answer below). Glad to hear I wasn't the only one having trouble :-)

Comment: Sadly, the current version of Dolphin HD (V8) no longer offers the option to move it. Text is generally left-justified. Why isn't the button default to possibly hide content on the right?

Comment: And then they brought it back. While I appreciate being able to move it again, I sure would like if they just stopped messing with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tap the gesture button to bring gesture drawing screen. On this screen, you can find a Gear icon in bottom-right corner. Tap it and you'll find 1st option on next screen for changing position.

[image: Dolphin Gesture Screen]

[image: Dolphin Gesture Settings]

[image: Dolphin Gesture Button Position Setting]

Answer (score 1):

On the Nexus 7 it is similarly hidden, you select

1. The gear
2. Gesture settings
3. Scroll to bottom <--
4. Change entry location
5. Select from (left,right,hidden)
6. Enjoy :-)